# Module '"*.vue"' has no exported member 'Hoge'. Did you mean to use 'import Meeting from "*.vue"' instead?ts(2614)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

### Summery

I've implemented Vue.js/Nuxt.js application.
In the application, I import vue file into typescript file.

typescript file

```js
import { Hoge } from '~/layouts/default.vue'
```

~/layouts/default.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
export interface Hoge{
  hoge: string
}
</script>
```

But I shows error on `{ Hoge }` saying `Module '"*.vue"' has no exported member 'Hoge'. Did you mean to use 'import Meeting from "*.vue"' instead?ts(2614)`

I want to know how to resolve this error.

### what I've tried

I already set `index.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are trying to import a type from a vue file but this is what I recommend:

Create a file `/types/shared.ts`
And add this inside:

```
export interface Hoge{
  hoge: string
}
```

Than you can import this interface like this:

```
import { Hoge } from '~/types/shared'
```